# Error: Found object is not a stat

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the following code:

```
library (ggplot2)
df=data.frame(score=c(1,3,5,9,7,8,4,1,2,6,1,6,2,1,3,1,3,5,8,4),
              age=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3))  

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=age,y=score))+
     geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=.1),aes(color=age))+
     geom_line(stat = "hline", yintercept = "mean",aes(group=age))+
     stat_summary(geom = "line", fun.y="mean",aes(yend=..y..),width=.5)+
     stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_boot",geom="errorbar",width=.5)+
     theme_classic()
```

But I get this error:

> Error: Found object is not a stat.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I used this before but now it's not working.I want to produce something like this:

[image]

I would like to have the mean bar but I could only produce something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7elY.png)

Comment: `hline` is no longer available as a stat.  You can use `stat_summary` with error bar to achieve the same sort of effect: `stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.y = mean, aes(ymin = ..y.., ymax = ..y..))`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Try this example:

>df=data.frame(score=c(1,3,5,9,7,8,4,1,2,6,1,6,2,1,3,1,3,5,8,4),age=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3))
> ggplot(df, aes(x=age, y=score)) + geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=.2),aes(color=age))+stat_summary(fun.data="mean_cl_boot",geom="errorbar",width=.5)

However I cannot place the mean bar. That's what I really wanted. 

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same result using `stat_summary` with the errorbar geom and setting `ymin` and `ymax` to be the summary statistic via the special variable `..y..`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = age, y = score)) + 
    geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = .2), aes(color = age)) +
    stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", geom = "errorbar", width = .5) +
    stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.y = mean, aes(ymin = ..y.., ymax = ..y..))
```